# Is it possible to use the Spread Toolkit on Amazon EC2?

Tags: architecture, amazon-ec2, cloud

The Spread Toolkit (http://www.spread.org) allows for easy distributed messaging using publish-subscribe semantics.

Is it possible to use this toolkit on EC2?

What other pub-sub message buses can be used on EC2 (other than Amazon's SQS)?

Answer (score 0):

EC2 gives you full O/S level access, so I don't see why you shouldn't be able to use Spread.  You might need to open some ports in your security group to enable communication between nodes, but other than that there shouldn't be any EC2-specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the spread-toolkit, but you should check if it uses multicast for messaging (not supported in EC2) and if it can deal with dynamic IP addresses - when EC2 instances are rebooted, they may get a different internal IP address (otherwise you need to buy so-called elastic IP addresses, which are fixed IP addresses).